# Asp.Net & MySQL databse project and it's working properly in localhost. when i'm hosting it in hostgator shared windows hosting, it's showing this

Tags: mysql, asp.net

This is my version of Asp.net

[image]

this is the error showing in web.config file after host and open

[image]

- Visual Studio Version 2015
- Hosting: Windows Shared Hosting
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- NutGet Package:MySQL.Data (Version:6.10.9)

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Post code and errors as *text* in the code itself. Images can't be compiled, tested or googled. Use the *correct* tags too . .NET Framework isn't .NET Core and 4.5.2 is out of support anyway. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2 but there's no real reason to use anything less than 4.8

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to distribute some required file. Why don't you try the [Publish command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975170/how-does-publish-in-visual-studio-work) to a local folder and then check the difference with the distributed copy of your app?

Comment: Why are you creating a web app using such obsolete versions anyway? *Especially* if you want to use a hoster? Chances are they don't support such obsolete runtimes.

Comment: The image complains about System.Web.Optimization which is obsolete at least since 2012 as [this possibly duplicate question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app). The project properties show a Class Library project, not a web app. What are you trying to do? We can't help when you post incomplete or worse, incorrect information. Are you trying to migrate a legacy MVC3 web app to a newer version?

Comment: If you have to migrate to MVC 4 because nobody supports the old runtime, you'll have to make a lot of changes, not just change the framework version. You'll have to replace any obsolete libraries with newer ones. The [ASP.NET MVC 4 migration notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#upgrading-an-aspnet-mvc-3-project-to-aspnet-mvc-4) show some of the other changes you need to make but as they say: `The simplest way to upgrade is to create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project and copy all the views, controllers, code, and content files from the existing MVC 3 project`